# Unplugging mysql remote

Tags: java, mysql, networking, timeout

I have my mysql server on a remote computer. I was testing a piece of code's behavior when database connection is cut off because the code observes database connections through DriverManager. When I stop mysql from windows' services, code doesn't have trouble adjusting to offline state. But when I unplug the network cable from the remote, database query takes at least a full minute before noticing anything and the program waits a decent amount of time for the query, especially if it was unplugged right before show slave status query. Why could this be?

Comment: it's called (un)graceful shutdown ... you have to implement a circuit breaker or just simply "fault tolerance" ...

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a network timeout. This is a long-standing feature of TCP / IP.

Your Java program connects to MySQL using a TCP / IP connection.  Those are designed to be resilient to network interruptions out there in the world. If one router someplace in Iceland, lets say, and operated by Cable and Wireless, let's say, goes offline, your TCP connection's packets try to find a different route.

When you abruptly disconnect a link-layer connection (ethernet) cable the only way your Java program can tell it's disconnected is when the TCP connection gives up and times out.

If you need to detect this situation faster than the OS handles it, you need to set up some sort of watchdog thread.

It's good you tested your stuff by disconnecting your cable. But, this isn't a very common failure mode in server software. (It IS common in connections between mobile devices and servers.)